# Remind Me disabled for email in its own window?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

When I have an email open in its own window in the Mail app on Mac, and I go to the menu bar, **Message** > **Remind Me**, all the options are greyed out. The only way for me to set a reminder is to go back to the main Apple Mail window showing a list of all emails, select the email in question, and then **Message** > **Remind Me** > **Remind Me in 1 hour** is no longer disabled.

This is a bit inconvenient since sometimes I open an email in its window to read it better and then I would be reminded to reply later on. But it seems I'm forced to go back to the main window to fetch this particular email to set the reminder.

Anybody else experiences this? Any workarounds?